# Puzzling issue with Hyper-V backup (volume shadow copy) integration and DPM 2019

Tags: backup, hyper-v, scdpm

I have a Microsoft DPM 2019 server that's been backing up various Windows Hyper-V VMs without issue until recently. No apparent changes have been made, but now a particular VM is failing its backup due to the SQLServerWriter failing after the backup completes (status 12).

If I disable the backup integration for the VM (under Integration Services) and run a backup, it's fine. I can re-enable the backup integration in Hyper-V Manager and run successive backups and they're fine. But if I then reboot the VM and try a backup, it fails.

Does the backup integration actually turn back on without having to reboot the VM? If it doesn't turn back on until the VM reboots that would explain why the backups work before the reboot but not after.

Does anyone have any ideas (other than keeping backup integration turned off) how I can fix the problem and get the backups to work correctly with integration turned on?

Finally, does anyone know what having backup integration turned on does? If I keep it turned off for this one VM what am I losing?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it seems that enabling the backup integration service on the VM requires a reboot to take effect. This could be due to a configuration issue or an underlying problem with the VM. You can disable other backup software or conflicting services or consider reinstalling Integration Services.